# Flask-WTF form populating integer fields and radio fields

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I'm trying to populate a full form under the condition that one of the field says "MATH& 142". this appears to work for some fields and not others.

### Here is the code:

```
def formFill():
    @app.route('/formFill', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    form = cifForm()
    if form.courseNum.data == 'MATH& 142':
        form.courseTitle.data = 'Precalculus II : Trigonometry' 
        form.publishInCollegeCatalog.data = True #NOT WORKING - Radio Field
        form.numCredit.data = int(5)  #NOT WORKING - Integer Field

class cifForm(Form):
    courseTitle = StringField('Course Title')
    publishInCollegeCatalog = RadioField('Publish in college catalog?', choices=[(True,'Yes'),(False,'No')], ) 
    numCredit = IntegerField('Credits')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

### I have tried to print out some of the values on submit and noticed something interesting about the types

```
@app.route('/formFill', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def formFill():
     form = cifForm()
    if form.courseNum.data == 'MATH& 142':
        form.courseTitle.data = 'Precalculus II : Trigonometry' 
        form.publishInCollegeCatalog.data = True# NOT WORKING
        print form.numCredit.data
        print type(form.numCredit.data)
        print form.creditIsVariable.data
        print type(form.numCredit.data)
```

**console:**

```
5
<type 'int'>
False
<type 'int'>
```

### I also printed when I set them programmatically:

```
@app.route('/formFill', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def formFill():
    form = cifForm()
    if form.courseNum.data == 'MATH& 142':
        form.courseTitle.data = 'Precalculus II : Trigonometry' 
        form.publishInCollegeCatalog.data = True# NOT WORKING
        form.numCredit.data = int(5) 
        print form.numCredit.data
        print type(form.numCredit.data)
        form.creditIsVariable.data = bool(False) #: NOT WORKING
        print form.creditIsVariable.data
        print type(form.numCredit.data)
```

**console:**

```
5
<type 'int'>
False
<type 'int'>
```

The output is identical, the variable assignments work, but I don't see these values in the rendered form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to recreate your problem, but I am just not seeing it. You might however find my results working with `RadioField` interesting and I can at least point you towards a working solution.

### This is your problem line:

`form.publishInCollegeCatalog.data = True# NOT WORKING`

The simple fix here is to simply do something like this:

`form.publishInCollegeCatalog.data = str(True)# WORKING`

**You are conflating `True` with `'True'`**:

### Working Example:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from wtforms.validators import Required
from wtforms import Form
from wtforms import RadioField

from webob.multidict import MultiDict

class SimpleForm(Form):
    example = RadioField('Label',
            choices=[(True,'Truthy'),(False,'Falsey')])

# when this data is processed True is coerced to its
# string representation 'True'
data = {'example': True}

form = SimpleForm(data=MultiDict(data))

# checking form.data here yields - {'example': u'True'}    

# This prints the radio markup using the value `True`
print form.example

form.example.data = True

# This prints the radio using the value True
print form.example
```

### What do they Render?

### First print:

[image]

### Second Print:

[image]

### Explanation:

The `RadioField` renders a string representation of the `value` part of the choice. This is right in line with the **HTML** specification. Treated here.

> value = string
>
> Gives the default value of the input element.

The `value` part of the spec is treated as a string to support a wide range of values. **WTForms** has no choice but to treat this type as a string when it does its processing step. Its the least common denominator.

### But what about my ints?

Once again this is not a problem that I am able to recreate. Every single `IntegerField` I create behaves exactly the same way. If you follow the example below your results should be the same.

```
class SimpleForm(Form):
    my_int = IntegerField()

data = {'my_int': int(5)}

form = SimpleForm(data=MultiDict(data))

print form.my_int

form.my_int.data = int(6)

print form.my_int
```

### printing out

```
<input id="my_int" name="my_int" type="text" value="5">
<input id="my_int" name="my_int" type="text" value="6">
```

which is what one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using:

```
form.numCredit.data = int(5) # This is defined as integer in your form
form.creditIsVariable.data = bool(False) # and so on
```

wtforms expects values in the proper datatype